# Like sql column name is followed by like

Tags: oracle

| LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| Mr. | Bean |
| Mr. | Jobe |

How to use like operators when input name is “Obe ”
Wanna match both column for the input name

SQL
Select * from name where
inputname like (‘%’ || (trim(firstname) || ‘%’));

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, that would be

```
SQL> with test (lastname, firstname) as
  2    (select 'Mr.', 'Bean' from dual union all
  3     select 'Mr.', 'Jobe' from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where lower(firstname) like '%' || '&par_input_name' || '%';
Enter value for par_input_name: obe

LAS FIRS
--- ----
Mr. Jobe
```

---

Or, maybe with the `instr` function?

```
<snip>
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where instr(lower(firstname), '&par_input_name') > 0;
Enter value for par_input_name: obe

LAS FIRS
--- ----
Mr. Jobe

SQL>
```

---

If you want to check both columns, modify `where` clause, e.g.

```
where instr(lower(firstname), '&par_input_name') > 0
   or instr(lower(lastname) , '&par_input_name') > 0;
```

As I used SQL*Plus for demonstration (and substitution variable), you might need to switch to a bind variable:

```
... where instr(lower(firstname), :par_input_name) > 0 ...
```

or use procedure's (function's parameter) or whatever you have to pass that value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` to compare one column or the other column and convert the input and the column values to the same case:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   name
WHERE  UPPER(firstname) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:inputname) || '%'
OR     UPPER(lastname) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:inputname) || '%'
```